# Android/Java "org.apache.http.ProtocolException", trouble with HTTP header answer

Tags: java, android, http-headers

Good morning, 
It's weeks that I'm trying to get some data from a webpage using Android. Usually I don't have any problem about that. But in this case the server is not returning a standard HTTP answer.

Just to give you the idea it should answer something like this:

```
Status=OK - 200
Date=Thu, 23 Dec 2011 10:16:17 GMT
Server=Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By=PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9
Vary=Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding=gzip
Content-Length=49
Keep-Alive=timeout=15, max=96
Connection=Keep-Alive
Content-Type=text/html
...
```

But it's only answering:

```
Status=OK - 200
...
```

So I think this is the reason I'm getting this error:

```
W/System.err(18227): Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
```

I used to try many different ways, but none of them seem to work with this webserver (even if **i can read the page with the browser**). 
I also tried to run the script and reading other webpages, from others webservers, and the script **is working properly**. But **there is no way to make it work with this webserver** (because of the http answer).

I used this metods:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
request.setURI(new URI(urlAddress));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

and this one too

```
URL url = new URL(urlAddress);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

I can't change the webserver... do you have any idea that can help?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: can you show the url you are trying to access?

Comment: This url cannot be opened in my case. Browser - Chromium. Try to open it with the embedded browser from your emulator (or device).

Comment: Probably they are doing some maintenance... but usually is working. Both in Chromium, in my Nexus S browser and in the emulator browser. Is there a way to open a remote page without using HttpGet or URL metods? - Thank you

Comment: you can use an external library, like curl in Linux or GET from some python library, but there should be a way to call that method directly from Java and I would try a few things, but the page is down

Comment: Thank you very much for your time Eugene. I will send an email to the server's admin and ask him to check why the server is now off.

Comment: omg dude, i have similar problem . 1 =1  Are u fixing this problem ??? I can't find way to do it (

Comment: and also.. u have responses ((( i don't have any response from url like u

Comment: Yes, it was a server's problem. I couldn't do anything (as far as I know), just a wrong answer from the server.